# Why do some literals disappear when passing from CNF to DNF

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

$(p \Rightarrow q) \land (q \Rightarrow r) \land \neg(r \Rightarrow p)$

According to wolframalfa the result is $\neg p \land r$.

Could you tell me how did this happen? where did $q$ disappear and why?

Comment: If $p \Rightarrow q$ and $q \Rightarrow r$, can you conclude something? (transitivity / modus ponens). Also, write out the XOR (exclusive or) in terms of NOT, AND, OR and you will maybe recognize it again.

Comment: $(p \Rightarrow q) \land (q \Rightarrow r) \land \neg(r \Rightarrow p)$ is not in CNF. Aside from that, why do you find it surprising that irrelevant subformulas disappear when you put a formula in a normal form?

Comment: Rewrite it as $(\lnot p \lor q) \land (\lnot q \lor r) \land r \land \lnot p$ and simplify.

Answer (score 1):

The only possibility that $\neg (r \Rightarrow p) $ is true is that $ \neg p \land r$. For ($q \Rightarrow r$) to be true also, we can take $q$ or $\neg q$, hence $(q \lor \neg q)$. That is also the case for $(p \Rightarrow q)$, since we already have $\neg p$, so we can take $q$ or $\neg q$, hence $(q \vee \neg q)$. Since ($q \lor \neg q$) is always true, we can remove it because it doesn't impose any restrictions on the proposition. Hence we get $ \neg p\wedge r$ as our final result.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $(p \to q) \land (q \to r) \land \neg(r \to p)$

- Assume $q$, then we have $(p\to \top) \wedge (\top\to r)\wedge \neg (r\to p)$, which is $r\wedge \neg p$

$$\begin{array}{l}(p\to \top) \wedge (\top\to r)\wedge \neg (r\to p)\\ \top \wedge (\top\to r)\wedge \neg(r\to p)\\ (\top\to r)\wedge \neg(r\to p)\\ r\wedge \neg (r\to p)\\ r\wedge \neg p\end{array}$$

- Assume $\neg q$, then we have $(p\to\bot)\wedge (\bot\to r)\wedge \neg(r\to p)$ which is $r\wedge \neg p$.

$$\begin{array}{l}(p\to \bot) \wedge (\bot\to r)\wedge \neg (r\to p)\\ \neg p \wedge (\bot\to r)\wedge \neg(r\to p)\\ \neg p\wedge \top\wedge\neg (r\to p) \\ \neg p\wedge\neg (r\to p)\\\neg p \wedge r \end{array}$$

So the value of $q$ is factually irrelevant to the evaluation of the statement.

That is why it "disappears" when the expression is algebraically simplified.